# Forward declare unscoped enum in class complains private

Tags: c++11, enums, forward-declaration

Why does the following c++11/14 code not work? Here I am forward declaring an enum within the class. Objective is not to have a huge - 100s of values of enums within the class - which makes the class unreadable. I cannot use a separate scoped enum for this - for political reasons.

```
class A {
public:
  // forward declare the enum
  enum B : int;
  void func (B b) {}
};

// The actual declaration
enum A::B  : int {
    Val1,
    Val2,
};

int main ()
{
    // B is unscoped. so I should be able to use it as below?
    int a = A::Val1;
}
```

## Compilation Error

```
tmp.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
tmp.cpp:13:5: error: ‘A::B Val1’ is private
     Val1,
     ^

tmp.cpp:19:16: error: within this context
     int a = A::Val1;
                ^
```

But the following code works :

```
int a = A::B::Val1;
```

Comment: Just a thought: Perhaps it's because the compiler can't know that `Val1` isn't declared in more than one enum in the scope of `A` or derived classes - and protects against this possibility by forcing it to be private.

Answer (score 0):

That error appears in G++ but not in Visual C++ and clang. Formally enum's id can be used as namespace, or can be skipped,  but last two do skip it by default, while latest g++ enforces it. That's changeable by compiler options. Use of enum  class' id is mandatory:

```
class A {
public:
  // forward declare the enum
  enum class B : int;
  void func (B b) {}
};

// The actual declaration
enum class A::B  : int {
    Val1,
    Val2,
};

int main ()
{
    int a = static_cast<int>(A::B::Val1); // no implicit cast
}
```

Comment: I probably didn't get your answer fully. `int a = A::B::Val1;` works without cast. Only that `int a = A::Val1;` doesn't work. Which I expect to work as it an _unscoped enum_. `int a = A::Val1` works fine if I put the enum inside the class itself in place of forward declaration. So my doubt is why is this difference in behavior.

Comment: @MGH for enum classes being scoped is mandatory, for  trivial enums, like one you're used, it depends on the setting of compiler, why, I not sure. May be it is treated as enum class by default? but no, that would require a cast.  If I remember right, g++ with  "permissive" flag will allow to do that.